# Postgres wraparound problems

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, postgresql-9.3, vacuum

I have facing one problem with my Production PostgreSQL and which is related to Wraparound Problem basically for over limit of XID range.

This PostgreSQL Production is running more than 1 year with loads of transaction and bulk insertion.

I searched lot in google but confuse and very scare about this critical error. Right now I am getting this error during any vacuum or auto-vacuum stuff. 
I have around 250 GB of Postgres Production Database and I have also set auto-vacuum for all tables.

```
Error and Warning are:

WARNING:  oldest xmin is far in the past
HINT:  Close open transactions soon to avoid wraparound problems.
```

I have also checked current open transaction but there is no any long running transaction in Postgres session.

```
Current database age of XID :
  Database       Age
"template1";  153163876
"template0";  153163876
"postgres";   153163876
"dispatcher"; 153163876
"qate";       195568300
```

above result I got using below query :

```
SELECT datname, age(datfrozenxid) FROM pg_database;
```

please provide your inputs as soon as possible because very soon, this will really create problem for my production database.

Comment: Can you afford to forcibly close open transactions?

Comment: Thanks Erwin, for but I didn't find any long running process for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Then a plain VACUUM `should` be able to do its job ...

Answer (score 4):

If you can afford to forcibly close open transactions:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(procpid)
FROM   pg_stat_activity
WHERE  datname = 'mydb';
```

Then autovacuum can freeze rows, or you can run `VACUUM` manually. You may have to prevent new transactions temporarily. Here are detailed instructions:

- [Force drop db while others may be connected in postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11893/force-drop-db-while-others-may-be-connected-in-postgresql/11895#11895)

.. except you don't `DROP` the db. Just `VACUUM` it.

Or Postgres will force a shutdown to prevent data loss. [Detailed explanation in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND)

Comment: In my case, the problem processes were idle transactions.  Another symptom is that autovacuum worker processes are not running.  As soon as I did the pg_terminate_backend calls as per above, the autovacuum workers returned and the pg_log warnings went away.